# Cloning Ubuntu to new SSD

Tags: 22.04, clone

There are a few questions on how to migrate Ubuntu to a new SSD, but either the posts are old or I could not understand them. In an expectation that there is an easier newer solution, I am posting my query.

I have recently purchased a laptop with 1TB HDD and installed Ubuntu 22.04 and other softwares.  Only 50 GB of HDD is occupied.
I want help in transferring Ubuntu to a new 500 GB NVMe SSD.  Following is the configuration of my existing machine-

- AMD Ryzen™ 5 5500U Processor
- DDR4 3200MHz

I am providing the partitions of my HDD in snapshots.

### [image]

[image]

Comment: What have you found so far and why didn't it work for you? When asking, we expect you to not only research before asking, but to share that research when asking. Otherwise, you're going to get the same answers you don't want and your question will likely be closed as a duplicate. Please edit your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving entire Linux installation to another drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741723/moving-entire-linux-installation-to-another-drive)