# Computer is fast but loads stuff slowly

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I’ve recently got a new PC which is much faster than my old one, and to make things easier I transferred the hard drive (with Lubuntu 22.04 LTS on it) from my old PC to my new one. While using the new PC, I’ve noticed that although video games run at very high FPS and I get good performance, things load very slowly. Booting up the PC takes around ~3 minutes and launching applications takes forever. I suspect it has something to do my old hard drive, but I don’t know. My new PC also came with an SSD, so if the problem is my hard drive, what’s the best way to clone my hard drive to my ssd? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Your question has the risk of being opinionated but this article may help explain the differences https://www.pcmag.com/news/ssd-vs-hdd-whats-the-difference. Personally, I'd do an install from fresh on the SSD but make a backup copy of any important stuff first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for the best way, but cloning your old hard drive is not the best way to install Lubuntu 22.04 on your new PC. The best way is to reinstall the operating system since you no longer need Lubuntu and Ubuntu 22.04 would be more suitable operating system to install on your new PC. As a bonus Ubuntu 22.04 is supported for 10 years by free Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) until April, 2032 while Lubuntu 22.04 is only supported for 3 years.

It's not the best way of handling this situation, but if you decide to clone Lubuntu 22.04 anyway follow the instructions at this Ask Ubuntu question: [Moving entire Linux installation to another drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/741723/).