# Issues cloning an external install of Ubuntu

Tags: external-hdd, nvme, clonezilla, cloning

I have a bit of a weird situation regarding cloning a drive.

I work at a university in the visual resource center. For archiving we wanted to have a local installation of a program called Access to Memory https://www.accesstomemory.org/en/ As I'm not much of a linux user (I've tried a few distros over the years, but never really stuck with it mainly due to gaming and needing to use Microsoft Office), my first attempt was to install AtoM in an Ubuntu VM running in Windows. When it got to the networking setup, I basically gave up.

The preferred setup for AtoM is natively in Ubuntu. As we didn't want to have a dedicated computer for just AtoM, we decided to see if we could install on an external drive. In my searching for how to make a portable install of Ubuntu, I came across this article: https://itsfoss.com/intsall-ubuntu-on-usb/ to make it a fully portable installation. It works perfectly. I can throw that drive at either a Windows pc or the older Macbooks that we have and it runs great. Initially I was going to put it on a thumb drive, but as you might expect installing Ubuntu was taking absolutely forever. I was doing this at home one night and had a spare nvme drive and enclosure sitting there so decided to switch over to that.

The problem is that the nvme is my personal drive so we want to put it on a drive owned by the university as well as simply making a proper backup of it just in case. I've tried using clonezilla doing a disk-to-disk clone which kinda works. (I've tried it twice. Once without changing the flags on the system disk and once with changing them like in the article above). The system actually boots from it, but then there are tons of errors, primarily along the lines of:

[1432.183216] systemd-journald[293]: Failed to write entry 923 items, 676 bytes0, ignoring: Read-only file system

When I boot into an Ubuntu install on my laptop, I can see the drive and the contents so it appears everything did get cloned, but obviously something is borked with it.

Is this drive recoverable and if so, how? Or if it's not and I have to clone it again, what changes do I have to do either in the system or in clonezilla?

Thanks for any help you can throw the way of a linux noob way over his head.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/741723/moving-entire-linux-installation-to-another-drive