# How can I migrate a partition to another disk which already has a single partition the full size of the diskknow

Tags: 20.04

I have a disk in use that I wanna remove to free up the sata port (so I can plug in my dvd drive and watch movies!) Disaster struck when I tried to shrink the partition on the target drive to make room for the partition on the drive I want to remove from the machine What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: There is no "best" way, but the way you are going about it makes perfect sense to me: shrink the partition on the target drive, create new partition on the target drive, copy old drive partition there. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Copy the partition using what command, dd?

Comment: That's one way, if the partition has the right size. But there will be other ways. I'm quite sure you will find one that suits you if you search AskUbuntu, e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/741723/134479).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving entire Linux installation to another drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741723/moving-entire-linux-installation-to-another-drive)